# Store dropdown choices as set array elements into specific variables

Tags: php

I have the following html:

```
<form action="" method="get">
<ul>
    <li>location 
    <select name="locationdo">
        <option value="tax_cb">Checkbox</option>
        <option value="tax_radio">Radio</option>
        <option value="tax_dd">Dropdown</option>
    </select>
    </li>

    <li>genre 
    <select name="genredo">
        <option value="tax_cb">Checkbox</option>
        <option value="tax_radio">Radio</option>
        <option value="tax_dd">Dropdown</option>
    </select>
    </li>

    <li>studio 
    <select name="studiodo">
        <option value="tax_cb">Checkbox</option>
        <option value="tax_radio">Radio</option>
        <option value="tax_dd">Dropdown</option>
    </select>
    </li>
</ul>
<p><input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" /></p>
</form>
```

What I want is to have array elements from `$which_tax_array` stored in separate variables based on choices that were made. Hopefully the code will explain better what I want to achive (but it doesn't work as I wanted it to):

```
if (isset($_GET['submit'])) {

        $which_tax_array = array('location', 'genre', 'studio');
        $what = array();
        foreach ($which_tax_array as $key => $tax_name) {

            $what[$tax_name] = $_GET[$tax_name.'do'];


            foreach ($what as $tax_term => $display_option) {

                if ( in_array($what[$tax_name], $what) ) {
                    $checkboxes = ','.$tax_term;
                } elseif ( in_array($what[$tax_name], $what) ) {
                    $radios .= ','.$tax_term;;
                } elseif ( in_array($what[$tax_name], $what) ) {
                    $dropdowns .= ','.$tax_term;
                }
            }


        }

}

echo 'cb '.$checkboxes.'<br>';
echo 'radio '.$radios . '<br>';
echo 'dd '.$dropdowns.'<br>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to do. I see a few possible issues -
(1) you are not closing your `foreach ($which_tax_array as $key => $tax_name)` until the end, so you are executing your next foreach too early.
(2) you have `$checkboxes = ','.$tax_term;` instead of `$checkboxes .= ','.$tax_term;` so you are overwriting your `$checkboxes` instead of appending.
(3) your `if ( in_array($what[$tax_name], $what) )` will aways be true, as you are checking if an array value is in its own array, so all your values will be in `$checkboxes`. I think you want to check if the value equals `tax_cb`,`tax_radio`, or `tax_dd`.

try something like this-

```
if (isset($_GET['submit'])) {

    $which_tax_array = array('location', 'genre', 'studio');
    $what = array();
    foreach ($which_tax_array as $key => $tax_name) {
        $what[$tax_name] = $_GET[$tax_name.'do'];
    }

    foreach ($what as $tax_term => $display_option) {
        if ($what[$tax_name] == 'tax_cb') {
                $checkboxes .= ','.$tax_term;
        } elseif ($what[$tax_name] == 'tax_radio') ) {
                $radios .= ','.$tax_term;;
        } elseif ($what[$tax_name] == 'tax_dd') ) {
                $dropdowns .= ','.$tax_term;
            }
        }

echo 'cb '.$checkboxes.'<br>';
echo 'radio '.$radios . '<br>';
echo 'dd '.$dropdowns.'<br>';
}
```

Comment: You have double closing brackets in your `else if` statements. Anyway, it is not working as I want it. If I just click submit straight away (when each dropdown option is set to `tax_cb` - I get: `cb ,location,genre,studio` which is CORRECT, but if I make different selections it is not good. For example, say you change the second (genre) and third (studio) options to `tax_radio`, in that case I get `radio ,location,genre,studio`, instead of `location` being assigned to `$checkboxes` variable. Do you get what I mean?

Comment: To try to simplify, say I choose `checkbox` for `locationdo`, `radio` for `genredo` and `dropdown` for `studiodo` , I would then expect to get the following when echoing out each variable: `cb ,location` `radio ,genre` , `dd ,studio`